# javafx column in tableview does not fit prefWidth

Tags: java, layout, javafx, width, tableview

I would like to restore the column width of every column in my TableView after a restart of my javaFX application.
Therefore I read an article which discribes how to achive this. Unfortunately the code did not work for me. The columns do not resize after the restart. (But the values for width and prefWidth did change correctly)

[Article - How to remember the width of TableColumns](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2515424)

I already did some reading but was not able to solve this problem:

- [Force individual column width in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267276/javafx-force-individual-column-width-in-tableview)
- [javafx 2 automatic column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152828/javafx-2-automatic-column-width?rq=1)
- [TableColumn wont take full size of the TableView in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484960/table-column-wont-take-full-size-of-the-table-view-in-javafx)

The resize policy for my table is set to [CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY) and this seems to be the problem. If I switch to [UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY) the columns get resized. But as I want the columns not to disappear when the user changes the columnwidth, I would like to stay with the constrained resize policy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mena by "But as I want the columns not to disappear when the user changes the columnwidth"?

Comment: If the resize policy is set to UNCONSTRAINED, the user can drag&drop the column border. The user can increase the width of the first column such that the subsequent columns are not shown anymore (the user has to resize the application window to see the columns again or decrease the width of the visible column).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and it's not clear what is being asked here, but I was having a similar problem (I guess) with setting the `prefWidth` of a `TableColumn`, which wouldn't work. So I looked into JavaFX code and I found that prefWidth is handled like this:

```
private final DoubleProperty prefWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "prefWidth", DEFAULT_WIDTH) {
        @Override protected void invalidated() {
            doSetWidth(getPrefWidth());
        }
    };
```

So I realized that the `doSetWidth` method was not being called because the width had changed, but not prefWidth. This happens for example when the user manually resizes the column.

It can be fixed simply by listening to width property and setting prefWidth, like this:

```
for (TableColumn col : getColumns()) {
    col.setPrefWidth(col.getWidth());
}
```